# Android - convert json string to JSONObject without removing the escaped characters

Tags: android, json

I convert json string to JSONObject using `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);` And the convert jsonObject to Java Object using gson

But it gives an error when a json attribute value contains quotes, 
like , `{ "length" : "10"" } (its, 10 inches)`

Edit :
i get data from server api in following manner :
`"{\"data\":\"10\"\"}"`
i replace `\"` by `"`, and which converts into `{ "data" : "10"" }`
this gives exception as it cannot convert jsonobject into java object
`org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 13 of {"data":"10""}`

How can i convert `"{\"data\":\"10\"\"}"` to `{ "data" : "10\"" }`

**Edit 2** : 
I was converting the string to JSONObject the wrong way.
By removing slashes, I was also removing the slashes of escaped characters.

**Solution** : Instead, I used **StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(jsonString)** which didn't remove the slashes of escaped characters inside json key-value data.

Comment: use \ before special characters like { "length" : "10\"" }

Comment: You should read JSON specification to know which characters are allowed in JSON.

Comment: @Abhishek Aggarwal please check my answer with output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `\` escape character before `"`. Here's what you should do:

```
{ "length" : "10\"" }
```

If you have to use special character in your JSON string, you can escape it using \ character.

See this list of special character used in JSON :

```
\b  Backspace (ascii code 08)
\f  Form feed (ascii code 0C)
\n  New line
\r  Carriage return
\t  Tab
\"  Double quote
\\  Backslash character
```

Comment: please see the edit in the question

Comment: You don't have to put \ in front of every ", but only before 10\"

Comment: I wasn't putting slashes before every ", that's how the data comes from the server side (serialized).  I got the solution, you can see "Edit 2" in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Please share your error as well.
As far as from your Question i can see there are 2 quotes near 10.

```
{ "length" : "10"`"` }
```

If you want to insert " for inches please provide `\"`.

Comment: please see the edit in the question

Comment: Please share us the error/exception log too.

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 13 of {"data":"10""}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jsonString = "{\"data\":\"10\"\"}";

String jsonFormattedString = jsonString.replaceAll("\\\\", "");

Log.i("Response",":"+jsonFormattedString);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
I/Response: :{"data":"10""}
```

**EDIT**

```
jsonString = "{\"data\":\"10\"\"}";

String jsonFormattedString = downloadDetails.replaceAll("\"", "");

Log.i("Response",":"+jsonFormattedString);

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonFormattedString);
String data = jsonObject.getString("data");
Log.i("Response data",":"+data);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
I/Response: :{data:10}
I/Response data: :10
```

**LAST EDIT**

```
jsonString = "{\"data\":\"10\"\"}";

String jsonFormattedString = downloadDetails.replaceAll("\"", "");

Log.i("Response",":"+jsonFormattedString);


final String regex = "([a-zA-Z0-9-]+):([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)";
final String subst = "\"$1\":\"$2\"";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(jsonFormattedString);

jsonFormattedString = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

Log.i("Final Response",":"+jsonFormattedString);

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonFormattedString);
String data = jsonObject.getString("data");
Log.i("Response data",":"+data);

data = data+"\"";

Log.i("FINAL VALUE",":"+data);
```

**LAST OUTPUT**

```
I/Response: :{data:10}
I/Final Response: :{"data":"10"}
I/Response data: :10
I/FINAL VALUE: :10"
```

Comment: this output will give exception `org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 13 of {"data":"10""}

`

Comment: @AbhishekAggarwal please check my **EDIT ANSWER** with output.

Comment: data is not numeric, its a string `10"` , entered in an edittext

Comment: data isn't `10`, its `10"`, I need data value as `10"`

Comment: @AbhishekAggarwal  please check my last edit answer with output. you can just add this line **data = data+"\"";** you got output.

Comment: if you have any query you can feel free to ask me.

Comment: appending `"\""` isn't the right approach. This is the data I'm getting from the server, and i won't know what the data could be. I took this json just for an example